# How to solve "The application failed to start. exit status 1" error when deploying shiny apps to shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps

So I am trying to deploy a shiny app, and although I have recently been able to deploy it without any problem (a few weeks ago), now I am getting a page that reads this error: An error has occurred The application failed to start. exit status 1"
[image]

The app also works perfectly when run locally, the problem is just when trying to deploy it to shinyapps.io. I have tried commenting the loading of the packages, but it hasn't worked.

In Rstudio, the output reads:
`Successfully deployed to <https://tadeu-apps.shinyapps.io/bags/>`

However, I still get this error.
I have looked at the logs of my application, and this is what it looks like:

[image]

I have tried removing the code relating to the "Possible missing comma at...." and the same error still appears. When I remove that part of the code, the log now looks like this, with the area in red being the part in common to both logs:

[image]

Comment: Well, the error messages seem clear enough.  You most likely have a syntax error in `app.r`.  But we can't see the source code.  Does the app run successfully when you test it locally?  Specifically, what does line 861 look like?  Are you sure that all the resources it needs are available on `shinyapps.io`?  Are you sure that you've not used any OS-specific logic or formatting in your code? etc, etc...

Comment: I had a few names with "~" in line 861, and I removed those characters. It now deploys successfully, thank you!